# Generating Server-Key on Android-Cloud-Messaging

Tags: android, google-api, urbanairship.com, google-cloud-messaging

Im implementing Urban Airship in an app.
I have followed all of the guidelines from both Google and UA.

The phone gets registered with UA and I get an APID back.
But I cant seem to push stuff to the phone. I get this error in the UA console:

> Received push with invalid authorization on platform GCM

I believe that the problem lies with the Android-Cloud-Messaging API key that I have.
The documentation from UA says that I should use a server-key. But I see nowhere to generate it in the Cloud-messaging part. I have generated those before when Ive implemented other push stuff.

So basicly my question is: How do I generate a server-key? Or is it not possible to generate one anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
 Had to register a new app under Registered apps. And use the new one for servers